# Simultaneous event's probability

Tags: probability, self-study

We know that for two independent events occurring simultaneously the probability formula is $P(A \,\text{and}\, B)= P(A) \, P(B)$, which is the Multiplication Rule. But does it work in these cases?
i) Find the probability of numbers divisible by $3$ or $5$ in a random selection from $1$ to $20$.
With the multiplying rule, it should be,
$P(\text{divisible by}\, 3) + P(\text{divisible by}\, 5) - P(A \,\text{and}\, B)$
Which is $6/20 + 4/20 - (6/20 \times 4/20) = 11/25$. But it doesn't work!! Why!?

Comment: Numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5 in the range from 1 to 20, your last term... there is only one such number.

Comment: The fact that "it does not work" tells you exactly that the events "3 divides $X$" and "5 divides $X$" are not independent if $X$ has uniform distribution on set $[20]$. But this in a cumbersome way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the multiplication rule needs the variables to be [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). In your case, the two variables are created using the third one $X \in \{1, 2, \dots, 20\}$ and they are $A = X \mod 3$ and $B = X \mod 5$. Independence *is defined* in terms of the multiplication rule, we can say that $A$ and $B$ are independent if

$$
P(A, B) = P(A)\,P(B)
$$

In your example, are there numbers in the support of $X$ such that they are divisible by $3$ and $5$? How many are there? This would tell you what is the actual joint probability. Check the table

```r
> X <- 1:20
> cbind(X %% 3 == 0, X %% 5 == 0)
       [,1]  [,2]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE
 [9,]  TRUE FALSE
[10,] FALSE  TRUE
[11,] FALSE FALSE
[12,]  TRUE FALSE
[13,] FALSE FALSE
[14,] FALSE FALSE
[15,]  TRUE  TRUE
[16,] FALSE FALSE
[17,] FALSE FALSE
[18,]  TRUE FALSE
[19,] FALSE FALSE
[20,] FALSE  TRUE
```

There is such value, it's $15$, so the probability is $1/20$, not $11/25$. And it works

```r
> mean((X %% 3 == 0) | (X %% 5 == 0))
[1] 0.45
> mean(X %% 3 == 0) + mean(X %% 5 == 0) - mean((X %% 3 == 0) & (X %% 5 == 0))
[1] 0.45
```

For a more extreme example, take $C = X \mod 7$, the probability that $A$ and $C$ are both zeros is zero, and they are clearly not independent. The result is not surprising because $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all simple functions of the common variable $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is incorrect, it's not the multiplication rule, it's the addition rule.

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$

Spelling it out: the probability of A **or** B happening is = the probability of A happening *plus* the probability of B happening *minus* the probability of A **and** B happening.

Comment: I think that the OP only meant to speak of last term $P(A\text{ and }B)$ when he/she used the words "...With the multiplying rule, it should be...".It is clear that the OP is familiar with both rules. This does not answer the posed question.

Comment: @drhab It does answer it in my opinion. I did not want to answer completely, as this is self study, but the boldened words are the critical parts which I wanted to highlight.